# How to create this early sun look?

Tags: photoshop, gimp, image-manipulation, special-effects

I have seen lot of images that look similar to this, where there is this whitened light

[image]

([image found on flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/88260951@N04/9921921106/in/pool-1449225@N25))

How to make image look like this in Gimp or Photoshop (prefered GIMP since I use GNU/Linux and have only that).

Comment: Please read this: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/q/3881/9161

Comment: It's interesting that you describe this as an "early sun" look. Can you describe more why this strikes you in that way?

Comment: @mattdm I think it look like cold morning. Didn't know what to write after read a link from BartArondson comment.

Comment: That's fine -- I just think it's interesting because I don't see that at all (other than the hat and jacket) and so wondered if maybe describing _why_ it looks like that to you would give you some more ideas for how to describe. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vignette + desaturate a bit with curves. Note that you need to adjust the red/green/blue channels separately, removing more red than green and blue. Is this the intended effect?

I should see the original to give more advices.

You should also check out Lightroom's vintage photo effects, if that's the one you are after, then study the settings in Develop, and reproduce the same in Photoshop or Gimp.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to simply have the black point moved slightly in to dark grey.  This fades the blacks a bit.  This appears to be the primary change from an otherwise "standard" photo.

Comment: As an opinion, I also wouldn't suggest emulating this look.  It's an attempt at "vintage" or being like an instagram, but in my opinion, it's really overdone and while it does have a place, it is most often used when it doesn't fit and as a result detracts from the image. (This includes the example provided.)